# Android : Switching and update layout

Tags: java, android, layout, switching

I have the application that contains the game hangman. I have created a separate activity on their responsibility for drawing. Here's the code:

```
public class DrawWisielec extends View
{
    Paint paint;
    int choose;
    public DrawWisielec(Context context,int choose) 
    {
        super(context);
        this.choose = choose;
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawRGB(0,0,0);
        Paint Circle = new Paint();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Circle.setARGB(255,255,255,255);
        Circle.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        Circle.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        switch(choose)
        {
        case 1:
            {
                canvas.drawLine(50, 400, 100, 300, paint);
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
            canvas.drawLine(100, 300, 150, 400, paint);
            break;
            }
        case 3: canvas.drawLine(100, 300, 100, 50, paint);
        case 4:canvas.drawLine(100,50,300,50,paint);
        case 5:canvas.drawLine(300,50,300,100,paint);
        case 6:canvas.drawCircle(300, 150, 50, Circle);
        case 7:canvas.drawLine(300, 200, 300, 250, paint);
        case 8:canvas.drawLine(300, 250, 250, 200, paint);
        case 9:canvas.drawLine(300, 250, 350, 200, paint);
        case 10:canvas.drawLine(300, 250, 275, 330, paint);
        case 11:canvas.drawLine(300, 250, 325, 330, paint);
        }
        invalidate();
    }
```

How do I switch between the various stages of drawing from another activity which the code is below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_mode_wisielec);

    DrawLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.WisielecDrawLayout);
    DrawWisielec draw = new DrawWisielec(this, choose);
    DrawLayout.addView(draw);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call invalidate() method on your `DrawWisielec` view:

```
draw.setChoose(2); // Change stage of drawing to for example 2   
draw.invalidate(); // Redraw view
```

According to Android documentation:

> public void invalidate () Added in API level 1
>
> Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible,
>   onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the
>   future. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI
>   thread, call postInvalidate().

It will call again `onDraw()` method, which you are interested in. Note that this must be called from UI thread.

Comment: I use this method, but i have exception, this is my code : This is method i launch what You wrote. draw.setChoose(choose) return exception. 
This is my method drawChoose :

 public void setChoose(int x)
 {
  this.choose = x;
 }

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: ThreadException , do I need to call invalidate and set Choose the thread? Sorry, My english is little.